# Changing validation rule in an Access form, based on user input?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

- Using Access 2010
- I know a minimal amount of VB

I have a table called *tblRawMaterials* which contains 2 important fields: *PartNumber* and *Diameter*.

I am using a form to fill in a different table with various information. The important information being: *PartNumber* and *TensileStrength*

In the form I allow the user to pick a *PartNumber* from a combo box with row source *tblRawMaterials*. Then they must enter the Tensile strength into a standard text box.

I need something to the effect of a Validation Rule, which changes the acceptable range (in the form) for the *TensileStrength* based on the diameter of the Part Number selected in the combo box.

Eg: User selects *PartNumber* 000001 with a diameter of 2" and the acceptable tensile strength is >150. User selects *PartNumber* 000002 with a diameter of 6" and the acceptable tensile strength is >130

I cannot use Cascading Combo Boxes because the user needs to enter decimal data into the *TensileStrength* box. I have tried using DLookUp() in the expression builder and creating macros, but I keep getting stuck. Thanks for any help.

Comment: No, how would a lookup table be used to solve the problem?

Comment: I need to prevent the user from entering too low of a tensile strength, so I was (incorrectly possibly) thinking that the restriction needed to be done in the form itself. I don't have a great understanding of lookup tables.

Comment: I intended to hardcode values in  the form's validation rules. The only options are: Diam.<2" = >150 strength, 2"< Diam.<4" =>140 strength, Diam. >4" =130 strength. The diameter can be any decimal between those values.

Comment: It needs to continually look up the *Diameter* associated with the *PartNumber*, because new Parts are constantly being added to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding another column to your combobox for diameter. *Be sure to update column count and column widths accordingly. (**1** for column count and **1;0** for widths)*

Be sure that the TS textbox is formatted as **General Number** so Access can handle non numeric issues.

I wouldn't waste my time on **AfterUpdate**, **Change**, etc event validation for the TS Textbox since they may not enter anything at the time they save the record.

Do the validation right before your code tries to save the data to the different table. I'd suggest creating a validation function that returns a Boolean. You can check for TS null value at that time. You can also refer to the new column in your combo box.

```
Function SaveTheRecord() As Long

  If DataIsValid = False Then Exit Function

  'Your current code to save record to the other table

End Function

Function DataIsValid() As Boolean

  DataIsValid = False 'default to false so you can just jump out of the function if criteria is not met

  If IsNull(txtTS) Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter a valid Tensile Strength", vbExclamation, "Validation Error"
    Exit Function
  End If

  'txtTS not null at this point

  '1st senerio
  If myCombo.Column(1) < 2 Then 'diameter < 2" (this is the new column for diameter)
    If txtTS < 150 Then
      MsgBox "Please enter a Tensile Strength that is >= 150", vbExclamation, "Validation Error"
      Exit Function
    End If
  End If

  'Check any other scenerios

  DataIsValid = True 'if we've reached this point, then everyting must be ok

End Function
```

You might want to create a label next to the TS textbox to inform the user of the range limmitations so they'll know before they try to save. You can do that on the combobox's AfterUpdate event. This is just a general example to give you the idea.

```
Private Sub myCombo_AfterUpdate()
  Call ShowPartRange
End Sub

function ShowPartRange() as long

  'if logics based on myCombo.Column(1)
  lblRange.caption = "Must be > 150"
  'etc

End Function
```